# how to achieve the performance of gallery control in Android UI in the environment of windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, android-gallery

Gallery control gives a good UI in Android os. I want to achieve the same performance in wp8. I find the panorama control in wp8 has almost similar performance but it always shows a 20 pixel on the right side. Also, the pivot control will show a black screen when slipping the UI without showing anything but the background image.

So I want to combine the ability of the two controls in wp8 to achieve the same performance of gallery control.

first, when slipping the UI, the right screen will show immediately to give user a continuous view.
second, I do not want to show the 20 pixel on the right screen.

So, can anyone tell me how to achieve it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, don't have time to test it at the moment, but would it work in the panorama control if you gave the left side of the PanoramaItem a margin of 20, and perhaps the right side a -20?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I find it does not work. I have found a method.